# What is backdoor memory access?

Tags: verilog, vhdl, memory, hdl

There is a term in HDL simulation/verification called
"backdoor memory access".

I've heard this a lot of times though I'm
not sure how is this implemented.

Also, there are a few references for this concept.

Comment: Could you link some of said references?

Comment: backdoor to me means any unintended access path, it dopes not single out any particular mechanism.

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: memory backdoor was mentioned in uvm user's guide page 108 [here is the link](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.1.pdf)

Comment: Has it to do with video RAM that sometimes has two buses? One for regular reads/writes (CPU side) and one for fast access by the DAC's.

Comment: Video RAM that has two buses should be called "dual ported" by anyone who speaks the proper lingo. The term "backdoor" is associated with deliberate security holes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question really needed a bit more context than simply "How does backdoor memory access work?". A link to a 198 page document for us to read, in order to guess what you are asking, is not really conducive to getting good answers.

Even basic context such as "in the context of HDL simulation" which appears to be what you're asking, would help.

That being said : when simulating a system (maybe testing a CPU you have implemented on an FPGA) you will need to connect the CPU up to external memory in your testbench. The memory model may look like:

```
entity SRAM is
   port (
      Address : in    unsigned(15 downto 0);
      Data    : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      Wr_n    : in    std_logic;
      OE_n    : in    std_logic;
      CS_n    : in    std_logic
   );
end SRAM;
```

and you might write this memory model yourself or download it from a vendor.

Now, loading a large program through these ports will take a lot of (wasted) simulation time. Ditto saving the program's output for later analysis.

However there is nothing to stop you adding more connections to the memory model, which are entirely separate from actual pins on the physical memory, and connect directly to your testbench.

For example you could add a backdoor interface consisting of the ports

```
  Filename : in String;
  Load     : in std_logic;
  Save     : in std_logic;
```

and suitable behaviour (reading a binary file) in the SRAM architecture.
Then in the testbench (assuming Progmem_Filename is connected to the correct Filename port) you can write

```
  Progmem_Filename <= "selftest.elf";
  Load             <= '1';
  wait for 1 ns;
  Load             <= '0';
```

and your program memory is loaded and ready to run.

Answer (score 0):

In a UVM RAL context “backdoor access” simply means that register or memory values are not accessed over the (simulated) bus but directly written or read to/from the register’s or memory’s signals. The big advantage is that it takes no simulation time (since no clock cycles have to elapse) and doesn’t cause any bus traffic, so no bus congestion etc.

It’s very useful if you want to do things like checking that writes have actually arrived and to do so without constantly reading on the bus. Normal reads on the bus have side effects which can mask bugs. For example I’ve had clock gating bugs where writes only worked if they were followed by a read. Or your address decoder can have a bug which makes both reads and writes go to the wrong destination.

Backdoor access is also useful to reduce simulation runtimes. For example you can quickly initialize memory values via backdoor access or read back all the values to make sure only the expected addresses have been changed.